# Excel 2013, AND function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm supposed to modify the formulas in cells B8 to B11 to display a blank if no boat ID value has been entered (cell B7). I also have to modify the formula in cell B13 to display zero if no boat ID value has been entered.

Normally I would use IF function, but in this case I have to use AND. I sincerely have no idea how to do this.

[image: Cells B8, B9, B10, B11, B13 have the VLOOKUP function. The only difference between them is the column number]
Cells B8, B9, B10, B11, B13 have the VLOOKUP function. The only difference between them is the column number.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/and-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9

Answer (score 2):

Use `IFERROR` function with `VLOOKUP` function".

For B7 you can use this formula: **=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B$7,$I$3:$O$28,2,FALSE),"")**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use AND,

Just use an IF as in the below:

```
=if($B$7="","", YOU VLOOKUP HERE )
```

`AND` is used when you want more than `ONE` condition to be `TRUE`, in your case you only stateda single condition:

*IF B7 is blank*